# Display Count of Foreign key in Other table

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

i want to display number of Users in that company for all companies. I am using User in-built Model.

UserProfile Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Company Model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    company_description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

View to display Companies

```
class CompanyListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.TemplateView):
    template_name = 'company/company.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
        context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['companies'] = Company.objects.exclude(company_name='Google')
        # Count of Users
        return context
```

Display Count of Users for each company in single template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I'll add a `related_name` attribute to the `user_company` field:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user_company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_profiles')
```

Then in your `get_context_data` method you just need to `annotate()` your queryset in the following way:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):   
    context = super(CompanyListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['companies'] = Company.objects.exclude(
        company_name='Google'
    ).annotate(
        total_users=Count('user_profiles')
    )
    # Count of Users
    return context
```

Note that you will need to import `Count` function as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Count
```

Then in your template you can access the count of users like follows:

```
{% for company in objects %}
    {{ company.total_users }}
{% endfor %}
```